# sql complicated two-way hierarchical relations

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have a main table `people`:

```
id name
1  I
2  Bro
3  Mom
4  Father
```

and I need to service relations between people. For this purpose, I have a table `relations`:

```
id  people_id   relation_id   type
1   1           2             2 //brothers
2   3           1             3 //sun
3   3           4             1 //married
```

The question is how to maintain such complicated kind of relations?

For example, user 3 has relation to 1, but because of relation 3-4, user 4 also has the same relation to 1. Another ex, 1-2 relation & 3-1 relation, produces 3-2 relation etc...

Maybe it is a good way to duplicate all relations or change design at all?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I think you should explicitly record all relationships.  What if 3 & 4 was a second marriage and 4 wasn't actually related to 1?

Comment: if you want to `model` the `family tree` then you'r design has problem, you can find too much about designing a db for family tree on the internet [here](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/genealogy/) is a sample

Answer (score 0):

If you have parent and child relationships, you don't need to have the sibling relationship type.  That can be figured out procedurally, because all child relationships of the same father or mother are going to be siblings.

Your relationship types should be:

- Parent of
- Married to

You do need reciprocal rows for the Marriages however.